# Showing that $x_i(k+1)=\frac{1}{a_{ii}}\left(b_i-\displaystyle\sum_{j=1,j \neq i}^{n}a_{ij}x_j(k)\right)$ does converge

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider $n$ agents that collectively solve the linear system $Ax = b$, where matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is invertible with non-zero diagonal elements, $a_{ii}$, and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Each agent stores a variable $x_i(k)$ as the discrete-time variable $k$ changes. At time step $k \in \mathbb{N}$, each agent performs the following:

$$x_i(k+1)=\frac{1}{a_{ii}}\left(b_i-\sum_{j=1,j \neq i}^{n}a_{ij}x_j(k)\right), \qquad i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$$

Each agent $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ then sends its value $x_i(k+1)$ to all other agents $j \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ with $a_{ij} \neq 0$, and they iteratively repeat the computation above. The initial values of the agents are arbitrary.

How can the following be shown?

1. The necessary condition for convergence, i.e., $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty}x(k)=x^*$.
2. Assuming the process indeed converges, how can we show that $Ax^*=b$?

For the first part, do I simply need to show that the modulus of $A$'s eigenvalues must be less than $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part $1$, yes.

For part $2$, take limit as $k \to \infty$ on both sides of the equation so that under the limit, $x_{k+1} = x_k = x^*$

That would mean that for $x^*$, we have:
$a_{ii}x^*_i=b_i-\displaystyle\sum_{j=1,j \neq i}^{n}a_{ij}x_j^* $ 
which when re-arranged is same as $(Ax^*)_i=b_i$ for all $i$

Comment: I understand the logic of taking the limit of the equation such that $x_{k+1}=x_k=x^*$, as this is what it means for the process to converge on a value $x^*$. However, I do not know how to show formally that $Ax^*=b$. Is there a way to show this algebraically?

Comment: @mathbioguy Edited the answer to that effect

Comment: Ah thank you so much!